# How to customize behavior of typeset button in GUI editor?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, compiling, texworks, sagetex

I use `TeXworks` to turn tex into pdf. There are some cases where I need to compile twice in order to get a complete document, such as referencing a labeled section. Also there are even more complex cases where the `.tex` file is compiled, then an intermediary file such as `.sage` file should be compiled first before recompiling the `.tex` file. Is it possible to change how the compile button behaves so that I do not need to go to the terminal everytime I need to typeset such a document? Are there other editors where this is easier? If so I am willing to switch to another editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Typesetting > Processing Tools > + to create a new tool, and fill it in however you want. If latexmk works for your use case, you could use that. If not, you could write a custom script and use that. Select the new tool from the dropdown next to the compile button.